# Python: max occurence of consecutive days

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have an Input file:

```
ID,ROLL_NO,ADM_DATE,FEES
1,12345,01/12/2016,500
2,12345,02/12/2016,200
3,987654,01/12/2016,1000
4,12345,03/12/2016,0
5,12345,04/12/2016,0
6,12345,05/12/2016,100
7,12345,06/12/2016,0
8,12345,07/12/2016,0
9,12345,08/12/2016,0
10,987654,02/12/2016,150
11,987654,03/12/2016,300
```

I'm trying to find **maximum count of consecutive days where `FEES` is 0 for a particular `ROLL_NO`**. If `FEES` is not equal to zero for consecutive days, max count will be zero for that particular `ROLL_NO`.

Expected Output:

```
ID,ROLL_NO,MAX_CNT --  First occurrence of ID for a particular ROLL_NO should come as ID in output 
1,12345,3
3,987654,0
```

This is what I've come up with so far,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('I5.txt')
df['COUNT'] = df.groupby(['ROLLNO','ADM_DATE'])['ROLLNO'].transform(pd.Series.value_counts)
print df
```

But I don't believe this is the right way to approach this.

Could someone help out a python newbie out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#consecutive groups
r = df['ROLL_NO'] * df['FEES'].eq(0)
a = r.ne(r.shift()).cumsum()
print (a)
ID
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     3
7     4
8     4
9     4
10    5
11    5
dtype: int32

#filter 0 FEES, count, get max per first level and last add missing roll no by reindex
mask = df['FEES'].eq(0)
df = (df[mask].groupby(['ROLL_NO',a[mask]])
              .size()
              .max(level=0)
              .reindex(df['ROLL_NO'].unique(), fill_value=0)
              .reset_index(name='MAX_CNT'))
print (df)

   ROLL_NO  MAX_CNT
0    12345        3
1   987654        0
```

Explanation:

First compare `FEES` column with `0`, `eq` is same as `==` and multiple mask by column `ROLL_NO`:

```
mask = df['FEES'].eq(0)
r = df['ROLL_NO'] * mask
print (r)
0         0
1         0
2         0
3     12345
4     12345
5         0
6     12345
7     12345
8     12345
9         0
10        0
dtype: int64
```

Get consecutive groups by compare [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed Series `r` and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
a = r.ne(r.shift()).cumsum()
print (a)
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     4
7     4
8     4
9     5
10    5
dtype: int32
```

Filter only `0` in `FEES` and groupby with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), also filter `a` for same indexes:

```
print (df[mask].groupby(['ROLL_NO',a[mask]]).size())
ROLL_NO   
12345    2    2
         4    3
dtype: int64
```

Get [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) values per first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
print (df[mask].groupby(['ROLL_NO',a[mask]]).size().max(level=0))
ROLL_NO
12345    3
dtype: int64
```

Last add missing `ROLL_NO` without `0` by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
print (df[mask].groupby(['ROLL_NO',a[mask]])
              .size()
              .max(level=0)
              .reindex(df['ROLL_NO'].unique(), fill_value=0))

ROLL_NO
12345     3
987654    0
dtype: int64
```

and for columns from `index` use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html).

EDIT:

For first `ID` use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
r = df['ROLL_NO'] * df['FEES'].eq(0)
a = r.ne(r.shift()).cumsum()
s = df.drop_duplicates('ROLL_NO').set_index('ROLL_NO')['ID']

mask = df['FEES'].eq(0)
df1 = (df[mask].groupby(['ROLL_NO',a[mask]])
               .size()
               .max(level=0)
               .reindex(df['ROLL_NO'].unique(), fill_value=0)
               .reset_index(name='MAX_CNT'))

df1.insert(0, 'ID', df1['ROLL_NO'].map(s)) 
print (df1)
   ID  ROLL_NO  MAX_CNT
0   1    12345        3
1   3   987654        0
```

Comment: Many thanks for the solution. If you have time, could you please describe what you are doing at each step? Kindly bear with my ignorance.

Comment: Sure, giem eme a sec.

Comment: One more doubt, how could i include the `ID` column into the final output file? Could you assist me on this also?

Comment: OK, but what is desired output? Because there is multiple `ID` for max `0`, here `7,8,9`

Comment: For `12345` `ID` can be `1` and for `987654` `ID` can be `3`. I'll edit the expected output

Comment: I am going to dinner, give me some time.

Comment: Sure, please take your time

Comment: I edit answer, please check it. You can also upvote my solution. thanks.